# Include entire album in Smart Playlist if one song matches criteria

Tags: itunes, music, playlist, smart-playlist

Is it possible to somehow build a smart playlist that deals in albums rather than individual songs?

IE, Find all songs without album art.

Sometimes songs without album art are in an album where the other songs do have art, so it's useful to be able to grab the lot and reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Smart playlists can't grab tracks that don't meet their conditions. You might be able to script something like that, however; find all tracks for albums in a smart playlist that meets certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! iTunes does have an Album art predicate, however I come unstuck at locating the rest of the album. I think scripting is probably the only option.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that there is an Album Artwork condition; it's Lyrics that it doesn't have.

Comment: Have a look at this script; it might give you ideas: http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=tracksalbumtoplaylist . It finds the album that a track belongs to and moves it to a playlist.